# Using Quser when a user session is disconnected (powershell)

Tags: windows, powershell

There is this awesome article here that goes into how we can use quser to find logged in users on servers and then log them off if we so chose. It's great when they have an active login that has a named session. However, it doesn't work if instread the session is Disconnected (Disc), because it doesn't have a sessionname. And when it doesn't have a session name, everything gets moved up. For example here is my code:

```
$connectionName = "MyServerHere"
$quserResult = quser /server:$connectionName 2>&1 
$quserRegex = $quserResult | ForEach-Object -Process { $_ -replace '\s{2,}',',' }
$quserObject = $quserRegex | ConvertFrom-Csv
$quserObject
```

If the server has an active login, my results are like this:

USERNAME    : myEmpId
SESSIONNAME : coolsessionname
ID          : 2
STATE       : Disc
IDLE TIME   : 54
LOGON TIME  : 11/3/2020 9:39 PM

But if instead that is disconnected, the results are like this:

USERNAME    : myEmpId
SESSIONNAME : 2
ID          : Disc
STATE       : 54
IDLE TIME   : 11/3/2020 9:39 PM
LOGON TIME  :

This causes a problem when I try to do this:

```
logoff $quserObject.ID /server:$connectionName
```

I don't actually even need the sessionname, but I can't figure out a way to remove it from returning in the initial quser, which would be the easiest method. Anyone have any ideas?